# try and catch in inserting python?

Tags: python

I am just thinking how to do try and catch with it, what i am trying to achieve is like this:

```
try:
dbSession.execute(
        "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)",
        {"username": reg_form.username.data, "email":  reg_form.email.data, "password": hashed_password}
    )
    dbSession.commit()

    return jsonify({'success': 'OK'})
except e:
    return jsonify({'error': e})
```

in js, error is passed automatically, but in python i see samples like this,

```
except ValueError:
```

is it possible to pass the e automatically in python?

Comment: Do you mean `except ValueError as e`? Also, [you should not use bare exception](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except). use `except Exception` or `except BaseException` if you aware of what you try to catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do `except ValueError:` if you want to differentiate your `catches` based on the `Error` you are getting. Here, you catch a `ValueError` if you expect an `int`, but get a `str` for example.

But you can just keep it generic if you want by doing `except:`.

As pointed out in Maor Refaeli's comment, you can name your exception `as e` if you like.

you can read more about python exceptions on [this link right here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch that Exception First. So here you need to catch the exception `ValueError` and you can write the error return message to the variable `e`.

```
except ValueError as e:
    return jsonify({'error': e})
```

Which is what this code does. Or if you donot want to catch a specific Exception you could just.

```
except Exception as e:
    return jsonify({'error': e})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print or return the Value error as below:

```
 except ValueError as err:
        print(f"Failed - {err}")
```

OR

```
 except ValueError as err:
        return jsonify({'error': err})
```